# Notion of surjective functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have some issues with fully understanding the concept of surjection.

For the proof of $A_{m}$ being a countable set for each m $\in$ N, then the union $A = \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} A_{m}$ is countable; my textbook states that we let $\beta_{m}$ be a surjection of N onto $A_{m}$ for each m $\in$ N and then define $\gamma$ : N x N -> A , $\gamma(m,n) = \beta_m(n)$. Then, it claims $\gamma$ is a surjection. If we let $a \in A$, then there is a $m \in$ N such that $a \in A_{m}$. Thus, there exists a least $n \in$ N so that $a = \beta_m
(n)$. So, it concludes that $a = \gamma(m,n)$ and thus it proves that $\gamma$ is a surjection.

The fact is, why would proving $a = \gamma(m,n)$ make the function surjective? From the definition of a surjective function, if $f$: A -> B is surjective, then $\forall y \in B, \exists x\in A$ such that $f(x) = y$. In this case, how can we prove that for all $a \in A$ this will hold true? For this case, it seems that it is only for a particular $a$.

Comment: Because $a$ is an arbitrary element of the codomain. To prove that something is true for every $a \in A$, we choose an arbitrary $a \in A$ and show that the property is true for that $a$.

Comment: So this means that if we prove the property for any $a \in A$, then this would imply that it holds for ALL $a \in A$?

Comment: @fogvajarash As said $a$ is an arbitrary element of $A$, you know nothing about it other than it is in $A$, so by proving something for an element which you know nothing other than it is in $A$, you're proving the property for all $a\in A$. Plus the terms 'any' and 'all' are used interchangeably. If this still confuses you, you might wanna read the relevant section of [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521446635), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, from the definition of surjective function, se say $f: A\rightarrow B$ is surjective ($f$ is onto B$)$ if $\forall y \in B\, \exists x \in A(f(x)=y)$.

So this means that if you want to prove that a given function $f$ is surjective then you must show that given $y \in B$ there exists $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. You don't need to show that some kind of property holds for all $a$ in $A$ here. Instead, you need to show that a property holds for all $y \in B$: the property $\exists x \in A(f(x)=y)$. So you must fix an arbitrary element $y \in B$ and then show that there exists some element of $A$ such that $f(x)=y$.